# array size stays the same even after memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, linux, ubuntu, dynamic-memory-allocation

i know this may be silly but i do not understand why after i use malloc to allocate memory for cars, cars size is 8. it does not matter what size i enter to carsAmount, please help.
when i checked the array size before allocating it- it was 8.
i tried to free it but got an error.
i tried using realloc-didnt work.

this is my code snippet:

```
int* cars = NULL;
int carsAmount;

printf("Enter cars amount:\n");
scanf("%d",&carsAmount);
cars = realloc(cars, (carsAmount)*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: tried this too: cars = malloc(carsAmount*sizeof(int));

Comment: what do you mean same size? are you aware `sizeof(cars)` will return size of pointer and not size of array?

Comment: When you say "cars size is 8", are you using `sizeof(cars)` to check?  `cars` is a pointer, and the size of a pointer on your system is 8 bytes.  `sizeof` is not telling you how many elements are allocated.  You have to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: i checked using sizeof(cars)/sizeof(int) to see how many element are in the array-returned value is 2,

Comment: OK, so if you check them independently, I think you'll find that `sizeof(cars)` is 8 (pointer size) and `sizeof(int)` is 4 (int size).  So that's why you'd get 2.  Same answer though -- it's not telling you how many have been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

From [realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) man page

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

> If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size)

Which is equivalent to

```
cars = malloc(carsAmount*sizeof(int))
```

> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated
>   memory that is suitably aligned for any kind of variable. On error,
>   these functions return NULL.

To check if allocation succeeded, simply check if

```
if (cars != NULL)
{
    // allocation ok 
} else {
   // Allocation failed
}
```

---

```
sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int)
    |            |
    V            V
sizeof(cars)/sizeof(int)
```

Is actually size of pointer which is probably 8 and size of int is probably 4. This is why you get 2.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question how you are trying to get the array size, but I am guessing you are using `sizeof(cars)` and always getting 8. That's because `sizeof(cars)` will give you the size of the `cars` pointer, and all pointers in a 64-bit architecture are 8 bytes long.

Malloc and realloc keep the size of the buffer internally but you as the user are supposed to keep track of it.